Rotating charts in QGIS
I have a point layer with stacked bar charts. I need the charts to always be on the same place, relative to the point (i.e. right to the point). I defined the placement of the charts by the points coordinates, plus a certain distance (depending on the map scale, so it is scalable). This works quite fine als long the map is not rotated.
Once I rotate the map (in map view or layout view), the charts won't rotate with the map but remain in their original position and are therefore on a completely wrong place.
I work with QGIS 3.28.12.
Is there any idea for the cause of this or maybe even a possible solution?

No solution here, but indeed it does not work as you and I would expect. Setting x and y values to x($geometry) and y($geometry) should move the diagrams together with the points when rotating... Not just with shapefiles. And I am on QGIS 3.34.4.

Thanks for your quick reply! So I'll figure a way to avoid rotations when using charts.
